# Random.Next does work, but it doesn't return every value

Tags: c#, string, random, console, char

I've started programming a character randomizer very recently. When you type "hello" into the console, the program will mix these chars and create a random string with H, E, L and O. It should be as long as the word typed into the console, that means, if you're typing in a 5-letter-word, my program will also return a 5-letter string.

Here's my code:

```
                string readLine = Console.ReadLine();

                int readLineLength = readLine.Length;

                Random r = new Random();
                char[] letters = readLine.ToCharArray();
                string randomString = "";

                for (int i = 0; i < readLineLength; i++)
                {
                    randomString += letters[r.Next(0, readLineLength)].ToString();
                }

                Console.WriteLine(randomString);
                Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to generate a random constellation of letters.");
```

`Random.Next` works fine, but if you type in the word "hello", the program will only mix E, L and O but completely ignore the H.

I hope my issue is pretty clear.

Comment: to be more clear, you want to print all the characters but in a random fashion?
Because it is random, H is not guaranteed. change your for loop termination condition to `i < 100` & see H is printed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you just happened to ignore the `H` randomly, because it wasn't selected inside the loop. To actually shuffle the array, use sorting using `OrderBy` from `System.Linq`:

```
string readLine = Console.ReadLine();

Random r = new Random();
char[] letters = readLine.ToCharArray();
string randomString = string.Join("", letters.OrderBy(x => r.Next()));

Console.WriteLine(randomString);
```

Comment: Side notes: 1. `String.Concat(...)` equals to `String.Join("", ...)` 2. `readLine.OrderBy(...)` is enough, there's no need in `char[] letters`

Comment: Orderby random is a quick and dirty way to shuffle and usually suffices, but remember that it isn't the most efficient way to shuffle for very large sets

Answer (score 1):

@Adrian answer is pretty good. However, here is an alternative which may be little simple to understand.

```
    string readLine = Console.ReadLine();
        int readLineLength = readLine.Length;
        Random r = new Random();
        var letters = new List<char>(readLine.ToCharArray());
        string randomString = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < readLineLength; i++)
        {
            int randomIndex = r.Next(letters.Count);
            randomString += letters[randomIndex].ToString();
            letters.RemoveAt(randomIndex);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(randomString);
        Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to generate a random constellation of letters.");
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want is to *shuffle* the supplied string which returns a random *permutation* of the input string.

For instance, given `hello`, you might return any — and more! — of:

- `lohel`
- `ohell`
- `lehlo`
- *etc.*

Simply picking characters at random from the string won't do it. Neither will sorting the characters randomly. Why? because `1` • `1` • `1` • `1` • `1` is a perfectly legitimate random sequence.

What you want is a **shuffle algorithm**. The *Fisher-Yates* algorithm is [one of] the best.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle